# Select unique elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given facts like

```
foo(1,a).
foo(2,a).
foo(3,b).
```

how to get a unique result `[a,b]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setof/3`](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/setof.html): The built-in Prolog predicate `setof(+Template, +Goal, -Set)` binds `Set` to the list of all instances of `Template` satisfying the goal `Goal`.

The construct `+Var^Goal` tells `setof/3` not to bind `Var` in `Goal`.

```
?- setof(X, Y^foo(Y, X), Result).
Result = [a, b].
```